# Set TabletPC Screen Orientation (PC Mode Landscape, Tablet Mode Portrait)

Tags: display, tablet

How can you set a TabletPC orientation to default to Landscape in PC mode and Portrait in Tablet Mode. Everytime I swivel the the display from PC mode to Tablet mode I have to hit the Orienatation button to switch the display from Landscape to Portrait.

I am sure it has something to do with the "Orientation Sequence Settings" but I am not able to get it to default as mentioned above.

I got to the "Orientation Sequence Settings" screen from Tablet PC Settings | Go to Orientation link

My system is:
HP Pavilion tx2000
Windows 7 RTM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work on my ThinkPad x60 either (not that I complain, sometimes I like to use my tablet in landscape mode and I don't want it to change automatically).

AFAIK, Orientation Sequence controls only the sequence bound to the "change orientation" tablet button.

I would guess you have to install hardware-specific drivers for Windows to even detect the lid mode change...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also agree with your assessment of the Orientation Sequence.